# Orthogonal polynomials on $[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

Are the orthogonal polynomials for the standard $L^2$ product on $[0,1]$ well-known? I couldn't find anything upon a quick web search.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_polynomials#Examples_of_orthogonal_polynomials

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Legendre polynomials $P_n(x)$ (see [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials)) are orthogonal on $[-1,1]$. So you can just set $Q_n(x)=P_n(2x-1)$ to get an orthogonal famiy on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Actually, I just saw that these are called the shifted Legendre polynomials: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Try for this $\{f_{n}(x)=e^{2\pi i n x}: n\in \mathbb Z \}$.

Comment: This is not a polynomial

Comment: Oh, I thought of trigonometric polynomial;