# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization: finding an orthogonal set

Tags: gram-schmidt

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Let $f_{1}(x)=x, f_{2}(x)=x^{2}, f_{3}(x)=x^{3} \in L^{2}[0,1]$ , Find an orthonormal set from $\left\{f_{1}(x), f_{2}(x), f_{3}(x)\right\}$ by using the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664638/orthogonal-polynomials-on-0-1

Comment: Have you tried using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization?

Comment: I have, but I honestly do not really understand this...

Comment: Using the definition of inner product on $L^2$ and following the orthogonalization process should be relatively straightforward.

Comment: Please, help me with a solution. I would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you find dot product of $f_1$ and $f_2$ in your space?